# Why can't Pandas's isin() work with numpy.int64?

Tags: numpy, pyspark

When trying to run the following code:

```
val1_index = df_playlists['pid'].isin(val1_playlist[0])
```

I received this error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

`df_playlists` is a Spark dataframe with the following column types:

> [('pid', 'bigint'), ('tid', 'bigint'), ('pos', 'bigint')]

and `val1_playlist` is a 2d-array of type numpy.int64 . I tried replacing `val1_playlist` with a simple Python list like `[0, 1, 2]` and it works just fine. So does this mean I have to cast each element in `val1_playlist` into int and then call `isin()` or should I do something else?

Comment: Yes. Spark does not work well with numpy dtypes.

Comment: I see. Thanks! @mck